# bash: oneliner to convert hex numbers in output to decimals

Tags: regex, bash, hex, decimal, converters

Does anyone know of a oneliner into which some output can be piped into in `bash`, to match and convert all occurrences of hexadecimal numbers and leave all other text untouched?

- maybe match rather arbitrary output which could be a hexadecimal
  shall somehow converted through a regexp, i.e.
  `/(0x)?[0-9a-fA-F]{5,}/`
- a leading `0x` shall not be neccessary, but
  also be handled properly
- there can be false-positives, if not
  specifying a minimum length of the numbers, but that should not be an
  issue
- the goal is to find solution which can be used with as much possible outputs having hex numbers in them

It should work on output like:

```
ssg sjas # cat /proc/net/stat/arp_cache | column -t 
entries   allocs    destroys  hash_grows  lookups   hits      res_failed  rcv_probes_mcast  rcv_probes_ucast  periodic_gc_runs  forced_gc_runs  unresolved_discards  table_fulls
0000000d  00000006  00000004  00000000    0000c3b9  0000c35e  00000000    00000000          00000000          0000965b          00000000        00000000             00000000
0000000d  0000000d  00000004  00000001    00000000  00000000  00000000    00000000          00000000          000007cd          00000000        00000000             00000000
0000000d  00000008  00000008  00000001    00000000  00000000  00000000    00000000          00000000          000006e0          00000000        00000000             00000000
0000000d  0000000a  00000008  00000000    00000000  00000000  00000002    00000000          00000000          00000704          00000000        00000000             00000000
```

Most other questions on stackoverflow only tackle the issue of how to convert single numbers between number systems, only do the conversion for a specified column or completely kill the formatting being present in the input.

Desired output should look like: (`column -t` is there anyway, it really just need to replace the hex values it can find, and adding leading zeroes to a printf statement is also not a problem)

```
ssg sjas # cat /proc/net/stat/arp_cache | perl -pe 's/(?:0x)?[0-9a-f]{5,}/hex($&)/ge' | column -t
entries  allocs  destroys  hash_grows  lookups  hits   res_failed  rcv_probes_mcast  rcv_probes_ucast  periodic_gc_runs  forced_gc_runs  unresolved_discards  table_fulls
13       6       4         0           50105    50014  0           0                 0                 38491             0               0                    0
13       13      4         1           0        0      0           0                 0                 1997              0               0                    0
13       8       8         1           0        0      0           0                 0                 1760              0               0                    0
13       10      8         0           0        0      2           0                 0                 1796              0               0                    0
```

I could not find a short viable/reliable solution via `sed`/`awk`/`perl` in the last two hours, so I came here for help.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: The desired output doesn't match the input, why is `0000c1c5` converted to `0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

perl using e flag to substitution

```
perl -pe 's/(0x)?[0-9a-f]{5,}/hex $&/ge' file | column -t
```

Answer (score 2):

perl with the autosplit switch:

```
perl -anE'say join " ", map {/(?:0x)?([0-9a-f]{5,})/i ? hex $1 : $_} @F' file | column -t
```

The -n switch provides an implicit loop over the lines of the file.

The -E switch makes available optional features like the `say` command *(useful to print something with an automatic carriage return)*. -E does also the same thing that the -e switch that executes the code given in parameter (instead of looking for a file to launch).

The -a switch (autosplit) splits each line on whitespace and populates the `@F` array with the parts (like awk does).

`map { } @F` processes each elements of `@F` and returns a new array.

`/(?:0x)?([0-9a-f]{5,})/i ? hex($1) : $_` uses the ternary operator `condition ? true : false`. When the pattern matches it returns the converted capture group 1, when it doesn't the original part.

Note that Perl is a language that takes account of the context. `$_` inside the `map {}` refers to a `@F` item, and `/(?:0x)?([0-9a-f]{5,})/i` is the short version for `$_ =~ /(?:0x)?([0-9a-f]{5,})/i`. *(outside of the `map {}` `$_` is the current line)*

Comment: @sjas: no my fault @123 answer is correct since `print hex "0x10"` *(quoted this time)* returns `16` as expected. You should accept his answer that is shorter instead of mine

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Thank you for great code, could you please add explanation to it too, I am a beginner in perl.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: I added more details in my answer but the best is to use the Perl documentation: `perldoc perlrun` or `man perlrun` or the online doc.

Comment: Still kudos to you for being awesome. :)

Answer (score 1):

With `mawk`: for every row but first row (`NR!=1`) loop from first to last column (`NF`) and convert current column (`$i`) from hex to decimal.

```
mawk 'NR!=1 {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i=sprintf("%d ","0x"$i)}1' file | column -t
```

Output:

```
entries  allocs  destroys  hash_grows  lookups  hits   res_failed  rcv_probes_mcast  rcv_probes_ucast  periodic_gc_runs  forced_gc_runs  unresolved_discards  table_fulls
13       6       4         0           49696    49605  0           0                 0                 38201             0               0                    0
13       13      4         1           0        0      0           0                 0                 1984              0               0                    0
13       8       8         1           0        0      0           0                 0                 1752              0               0                    0
13       10      8         0           0        0      2           0                 0                 1775              0               0                    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the confusion.  Here's a one-liner that uses that feature of bash:

```
cat /proc/net/stat/arp_cache | sed -e '2,$s/\s*\([0-9a-f][0-9a-f]*\)\s*/ \$\(\( 0x\1 \)\) /g' -e 's/^/echo /' | bash | column -t
entries  allocs  destroys  hash_grows  lookups  hits  res_failed  rcv_probes_mcast  rcv_probes_ucast  periodic_gc_runs  forced_gc_runs  unresolved_discards  table_fulls
8        2       0         0           0        0     0           0                 0                 0                 0               0                    0
8        0       0         0           211      58    0           0                 0                 0                 0               0                    0
8        2       0         0           6319     1677  0           0                 0                 3882              0               0                    0
8        4       0         0           4731     1299  0           0                 0                 0                 0               0                    0
```

Comment: You did add another answer and added a comment yourself that you like your new answer? That's just 'meh'.

Comment: No.  I was responding to another comment (now deleted, apparently), that recommended I replace `> tmp$$ && source ./tmp$$ ` with `| bash`.  I guess he decided to delete his comment since I edited my answer per his suggestion.

Comment: Ah nice. +1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

with `GNU awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{IFS=OFS="\t"}NR==1{print $0}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(i!=NF){printf "%s%c",strtonum("0x"$i),OFS}else{printf "%d\n",strtonum("0x"$i)}}' filename
```

Comment: This is quite similar to what I have had already, but does not work as expected. I.e. `0000000d` gets converted to `0` instead of `13`.

Answer (score -1):

A leading `0` is considered to be octal, and a leading `0x` is considered to be hexadecimal.  If your numbers conform to that standard, then `$(( <number> ))` will convert them to decimal:

```
$ echo $(( 0x1b ))
27
$ echo $(( 014 ))
12
```

Comment: This was explicitly not about converting lonely numbers but complete outputs.